# Subgrid in jsgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsgrid

I am trying to show the data history in jsgrid as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137638/subrows-in-jsgrid/45393085#45393085).

```
 $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
   ...
   rowRenderer: function(item) {
        var row = $("<tr>");
        var historyGrid = $('<tr>').addClass('nested-grid').hide();
                historyGrid.jsGrid({
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "auto",
                    editing: false,
                    data: [{"a":"d1","b": "d2"},{"a":"d3","b":"d4"},{"a":"d5","b":"d6"}],
                    heading: false,
                    fields: [{ name: "a", type: "text"}, {name: "b",type: "text"}]
                })
                var items= Object.keys(item);
                items.forEach(function(key){
                    if(key!=items[items.length-1]) {
                        var cell = $("<td>").addClass("jsgrid-cell").append(item[key]);//line 1
                        row.append(cell);
                    }
                });
                row.click(function () {
                    historyGrid.toggle();
                })
                row.append(historyGrid);    
                return row.add(historyGrid);
        }
});
```

The history appears as below. I want to display in such a way that, it spans the entire blank(row) area.

[image]

if I change it `tr` to `td` at line 1, it appears as below

[image]

Any help?